# Filter a gridview column that is processed by a function in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a column named `wp_status`. If person A, person B, person C, person D approves a work, the value of column `wp_status` will be changed to `Approved`, else the value will be as it is in the database - `Assigned`.

The code to change the value dynamically in the gridview is -

```
[
               'label' => 'Status',
               'attribute'=>'wp_status',
'value' => function ($model) {
                   return $model->Status();
               }
            ],
```

And the function Status in model Workpermit is -

```
public function Status()
    {

        //$data = Workpermit::findOne($this->id);
        $total = $this->wp_status;

        if($this->wp_type == 'Safe Work Permit' && $this->wp_apoapproval == 'Approved' && $this->wp_spsapproval == 'Approved' && $this->wp_officerapproval == 'Approved'){ 
           $total = 'Approved';            
        }
        return $total;
    }
```

This works fine so far. But I'm not sure how to filter it with Kartik Select2 widget. I tried like following -

```
[
               'label' => 'Status',
               'attribute'=>'wp_status',
               'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Workpermit::Status()->asArray()->all(), 'total', 'total'),
                'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true],
                                    ],
                'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Permit Status'],
               'value' => function ($model) {
                   return $model->Status();
               }
            ],
```

And here I'm getting error - `Using $this when not in object context`

[image]

Comment: You are calling `Workpermit::Status()` in the filter value which treats this method as static. Shouldn't be `Workpermit::find()` ?

Comment: Hi Bizley, in the column wp_status in database, I don't have the value "Approved". It's assigned to the column dynamically when 4 person approves it. If I make the filter as (Workpermit::find()->asArray()->all(), 'wp_status', 'wp_status' ) I don't get the value 'Approved' in the filter option.

Comment: All right but you can not call static method and use `$this` inside without instantiating new object.

Comment: Yeah.. I got to know from other posts also. But what will be the workaround? My objective is to change the value of column wp_status to Approved, when 3 fields(wp_apoapproval,wp_spsapproval,wp_officerapproval) are updated as Appoved. Also I need to filter the column with Kartik select2 widget. Let me know of other approach to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

could be uisng a getter

```
public function getStatus()
{

    //$data = Workpermit::findOne($this->id);
    $total = $this->wp_status;

    if($this->wp_type == 'Safe Work Permit' && $this->wp_apoapproval == 'Approved' && $this->wp_spsapproval == 'Approved' && $this->wp_officerapproval == 'Approved'){ 
       $total = 'Approved';            
    }
    return $total;
}
```

the call `$model->status` (status lowercase)

```
[
           'label' => 'Status',
           'attribute'=>'wp_status',
           'value' => function ($model) {
               return $model->status;
           }
        ],
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, getting below error - 'Calling unknown method: frontend\modules\workpermit\models\Workpermit::status()'

Comment: @Tanmay Use `return $model->status or $model->getStatus()`.

Comment: Now, I'm getting output. One criteria still remains. I have to filter the column. In the column wp_status now I have 2 entries - 1. Assigned(coming from database), 2. Approved (That we're imposing dynamically). How can we filter Approved? When I'm filtering Approved, no entry is showing in gridview. I have following in WorkpermitSearch model - "->andFilterWhere(['like', 'wp_status', $this->wp_status])'

Comment: @Tanmay  for filter you must change the  related  modelSearch . you can take a look at this tutorial for filter a calculated  field see  scenario 1 http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/